# My Android devices won't scan the QR code generated in the CLI using tns preview

Tags: android, nativescript

I don't know if anybody has a solution but my iPhone 6 & 7 scan the QR code with no problem, but my Android devices don't scan it. I've tried a cell and tablet running Android but nothing happens. It's like I'm point it a nothing. No feedback on anything happening.

Comment: Whats your OS version? Did you try scanning it with third party scanners, of course that wouldn't make it work but at least helps to understand whether its problem with Playground app alone.

Comment: I can scan the QR code on the NativeScript site. So it does work,  it just won't scan the one generated by the CLI

Comment: Any updates on this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem too. My iPhone scans it okay, but not my Android

Answer (score 4):

It could be the IDE you are using. My issue was that my terminal in Webstorm made the QR code unscannable while the same QR code in your computer's terminal application works fine.